# Oracle to SQL Server large-scale Migration

Tags: sql-server, r, oracle, csv, rodbc

I am trying to migrate a very large scale of rows and columns dynamically from Oracle to SQL Server. I am trying to automate this for about 20 tables daily.

My process is as follows:

1. Run Oracle configuration script: runs query which returns the Oracle table data, but the data has duplicates and bad data
2. Oracle Format Script: calls config script and then fixes the data to be accurate (deletes duplicates and bad data). Returns the data to a .txt with '~' separators
3. `.txt` to `.csv`: (this is my workaround/hack) Using Excel, I open all of the .txt files and use the AutoFormat to change them into perfectly formatted .csv's. (By the manual delimiter option, because when I use the auto-delimiter='~', it comes up with random one letter columns)
4. R: using the newly generated .csv's, I create table structures based on these headers in SQL Server
5. R: using the data collected from running the format script for each table, I have ~20 .txt files. I load them into R Studio and then attempt to insert new data using the following script:

Initialization:

RScript which loads the table structure of one .CSV

```
library(RODBC)
#set table name
  tname <- "tablename"
#connect to MSSQL
  conn <- odbcDriverConnect("driver={SQL Server};
                            Server=serv; Database=dbname; 
                            Uid=username; Pwd=pwd;trusted_connection=yes")
  #get df headers from .csv      
  updatedtables <- read.csv(file = paste("<PATH>", tname, ".csv", sep=""), sep = ",")
  #save to MSSQL
  save <- sqlSave(conn, updatedtables, tablename = paste("dbo.",tname, sep = ""), append = F, rownames = F, verbose = T, safer = T, fast = F)


  #add update record in log file
  write(paste(Sys.time(), ": Updated dbo.",tname, sep=""), file = "<PATH>", append = TRUE)


  odbcClose(conn)
  return(0)
```

I run this code for each .csv to initialize the table structures

Dynamic things:

RScript which attempts to load data from .txt to existing table structures:

```
library(RODBC)
##~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ Oracle to MSSQL Automation Script ~~~~~~~~~~
#.bat script first runs which updates .txt dumps containing Oracle database info using configuration and format .sql queries for each table.

#function that writes to a table tname using data from tname.txt
writeTable <- function (tname){

#connect to MSSQL
conn <- odbcDriverConnect("driver={SQL Server};
                            Server=serv; Database=db; 
                            Uid=uid; Pwd=pw;trusted_connection=yes")
#remove all data entries for table
res <- sqlQuery(conn, paste("TRUNCATE TABLE dbo.", tname, sep = ""))

#load updated data from .txt files
#this skips three because of blank lines and skipping the headers
 updatedtables <- read.csv(file = paste("<PATH>", tname, ".txt", sep=""),skip=3, sep = "~")

**ERROR**
#save to MSSQL
 save <- sqlSave(conn, updatedtables, tablename = paste("dbo.",tname, sep = ""), append = T, rownames = F, verbose = F, safer = T, fast = F)


#add update record in log file
write(paste(Sys.time(), ": Updated dbo.",tname, sep=""), file = "<PATH>", append = TRUE)

  #close connection
  odbcClose(conn)
    return(0)
}


#gets all file names and dynamically inputs the data for every file in the path directory
update <- function(){


  #insert line separator for log organization which represents new script run
  write("-UPDATE--------------------", file = "<PATH>", append = T)

  path = "<PATH>"
  #save all .txt file names in path to vector
  file.names <- dir(path, pattern =".txt")


  #go through path's files
  for(i in 1:length(file.names)){
    #get proper table name of file.names[i]
    temp <- gsub(".txt", "", file.names[i])
    #call helper func
   writeTable(temp)
  }

}
#run
update()
```

This file contains the error. Everything works and loads, except the line `save <- sqlSave(conn, updatedtables, tablename = paste("dbo.",tname, sep = ""), append = T, rownames = F, verbose = F, safer = T, fast = F)`, which returns the error

> Error in `colnames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = c("QUOTENUMBER", "ENTITYPRODUCTITEMID", :
>    length of 'dimnames' [2] not equal to array extent

Any suggestions on what to do?

This is an example of the way the text dumps look (without spaces and with dummy data)
http://pastebin.com/kF8yR1R0